# Compiz "Show Mouse" alternative for Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-effects

I would love to have that very cool [Compiz "Show Mouse" functionality](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sC8D7-ah65Q) in Windows 7.

Do you guys know a Windows alternative for Compiz "Show Mouse" that will give me a cool mouse trail particle effect?

Answer (score 1):

I dug one up called [ViVi Cursor](http://www.vivisoftware.com/vivi_cursor.htm) which comes at $9.99 and has a few styles, including:

[image]

(Sorry for that gif, but it shows what the effect can be like)